# How do I convert a list to a tuple without angering mypy?

Tags: python, mypy

I have a list (of length two) and I want to convert it to a tuple

```
from typing import List, Tuple

l: List[int] = [1, 2]
assert len(l) == 2
t: Tuple[int, int] = tuple(l)
```

No matter what I do, I get the error message:

```
Incompatible types in assignment
(expression has type "Tuple[int, ...]", variable has type "Tuple[int, int]")
```

I've tried splicing

```
t: Tuple[int, int] = tuple(l)[0:2]
t: Tuple[int, int] = tuple(l[0:2])
```

and recreating

```
t: Tuple[int, int] = tuple([l[0], l[1]])
t: Tuple[int, int] = l[0], l[1]  # strangely invalid syntax, even though t = l[0], l[1] is valid
```

and I've read through [the docs](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kinds_of_types.html#tuple-types), but I haven't found any way to do this cleanly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the tuple function, use the parenthesis syntax.

```
t: Tuple[int, int] = (l[0], l[1])
```

Comment: I feel sheepish.

Comment: if you have a tuple of variable length, you may opt for Tuple[int, ...]